# Sniffing Python urllib2.httperror content and passing it along

Tags: python, exception, urllib2

In some python code, I am using a library to wrap requests to a web service. The behaviour I intend is that any HTTPErrors have their content output with a logging.error along with the status code, and the error passed along:

```
def my_request_thing(api, other_stuff):
  request = make_request_from(api, other_stuff)
  try:
    with closing(urllib2.urlopen(request)) as fd:
      return fd.read()
  except HTTPError as e:
    logging.error("Error from server: %s\n%s", e.code, e.read())
    raise
```

This code will log, and pass the error along, with one problem, the exceptions content is exhausted in e.read. This code is intended to be used to most clients to the API substituting things like root paths and http headers...
I may then have another function for more domain specific stuff using this:

```
function get_my_thing(thing_id, conditions):
  try:
    return json.loads(my_request_thing(<thing_id + conditions into api and stuff...>))
  except HTTPError as e:
    if e.code == 404 and "my thing does not exist" in e.read():
      return False
    else:
      raise e
```

Note here that this also tries to get data with e.read - which is now empty, and may still reraise the error. This will fail to work - there is not data in e.read here.

Is there a good way to reraise this exception such that the content is not exhausted, but so I can sniff out particular exception types and log them all on the way?

Comment: Can't you use `e.reason` instead? That wouldn't destruct after inspection.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, e.reason does not hold the content returned by the server. The 404 tells me that something was not found. The content will suggest what was missing.

Comment: In that case, why don't you inject the results from `e.read()` into the exception as a data member upon seeing it for the first time? For example, derive your own error class from `HTTPError` with an empty `self.content`. When catching an exception for the first time, fill `self.content` from `self.read()`. Next handlers can inspect `e.content`.

Comment: This was what I did in an implementation - I think deriving makes sense, as initially I was monkey-patching HTTPError, which I felt uncomfortable with because it created a new non-standard interface to it - often a bad idea. It may be elegance can be found here by looking how the python requests lib handles this.

Comment: requests stuffs detail into a "response" object, which is returned, or stuffed into exceptions it raises. This has headers, content and status code. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response. Has me considering requests instead of urllib2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Karel Kubat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675751/sniffing-python-urllib2-httperror-content-and-passing-it-along/31664931?noredirect=1#comment45681624_28675751) comment, why don't you inject the results from `e.read()` into the exception as a data member upon seeing it for the first time?

For example, derive your own error class from `HTTPError` with an empty self.content. When catching an exception for the first time, fill `self.content` from `self.read().` Next handlers can inspect `e.content`.

Comment: This is the answer, although Karel Kubat should get credit for that comment.